# how to apply filter to each row after the group by in sql

Tags: sql, conditional-aggregation

i have a table -
Table=emp

```
eno ename designation sal   mgr  deptno
1   aaa   salesman    7000  2    10
2   bbb   manager     17000 3    10
3   ccc   president   40000 null 30
4   ddd   clerk       5000  5    20
5   eee   manager     20000 3    20
```

Q)per job how many employees earn more than 10000 ?

i want result -

```
designation  count(*)
salesman     0
manager      2
clerk        0
president    1
```

query-

```
SELECT designation, count(*) FROM emp WHERE sal>10000 GROUP BY designation;
```

getting result-

```
designation count(*)
manager     2
president   1
```

Please tell me how to apply filter on each row after group by clause ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT designation, sum(case when sal > 10000 then 1 else 0 end) as count
FROM emp 
GROUP BY designation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM AND GROUP BY functions :

```
  SELECT designation, SUM(CASE WHEN sal > 10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count
  FROM Your_table 
  GROUP BY designation;
```